# JMeter - How can I send token and using it to the next request?

Tags: jmeter

How to send token with this request?

1. I send POST request with the body:
   https://joxi.ru/MAjyLKZHj7lXN2
2. I created Regular Expression Extractor to take a token:
   https://joxi.ru/LmGLPxGHwdPL32
3. Then I put this token to the next POST request:
   https://joxi.ru/Y2L3PVBh7GPJGm
4. After I run my test it fails:
   At LOGIN a take a token:
   https://joxi.ru/E2pjOoXi7eLMnr

> BUT another request fails: https://joxi.ru/Vm6O80lf4ql8N2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your Log_in thread group, the token is already stored in the BEARER variable.

You can access it on the Header Manager:

[image]

(Change *key* for *BEARER* and it should work)

Also be careful with typos, the name of the Header key is Aut**h**otization.

Comment: Thank's, very grateful for the help

Comment: Most welcome Dmitry. If the answer was solved your issue, could you mark it as accepted? It really helps to keep the people engaged in the site.